# How could implement a dropdown menu via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a dropdown menu at 820px, I already have the navbar toggle however I can't seem to wrap my head around how I am going to get the navbar content to dropdown while keeping it responsive on smaller screens. If someone could just point me in the right direction that would be incredibly helpful, thank you.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.left-elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-inline-start: 1.5em;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-inline-end: 4em;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.logo {
  padding-inline-start: 0.5em;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.btn-login {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #90E0EF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
  width: 8em;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 35rem;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-header {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  height: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-text {
  width: 40%;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .left-elements {
    display: none;
  }
  .right-elements {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: flex;
    padding-inline-end: 2em;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.btn-container>button {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #90E0EF;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
  width: 11em;
}

.btn-sourcecode {
  background-color: #90E0EF;
}

.btn-getstarted {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-text {
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1112px) {
  .main-header {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 595px) {
  .main-header {
    font-size: 2rem;
    height: 20%;
  }
  .heading-text {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .decentralized {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  .main-header {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .btn-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .main-header {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

.container-decentralized {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 21rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.decentralized {
  height: 21em;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1112px) {
  .main-header {
    font-size: 3em;
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .decentralized {
    height: 15rem;
  }
}

.hover-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 0 rgba(0, 214, 243, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow ease-in 0.1s;
}

.why-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 12rem;
}

.header-why {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.card {
  background-color: #90E0EF;
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: #90E0EF solid 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  height: 17rem;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.card-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-text {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Screen larger than 600px 2 column */

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}


/* Screen larger than 900px 3 columns */

@media (min-width: 941px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href=""><img class="logo" src="/images/Donation_Hub-5-2-removebg-preview.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="left-elements">
      <a href="">About</a>
      <a href="">Pricing</a>
      <a href="">Integrations</a>
      <a href="">Support</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-elements">
      <a href="" class="btn-login hover-btn">Log In</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-toggle">
      <a href=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill="#90E0EF" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
              </svg></a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="heading">
    <h1 class="main-header">A Powerful Decentralized, Open-Source Fundraising Software</h1>
    <p class="heading-text">Manage your donations without having your data stolen and sold without your consent.</p>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="btn-sourcecode hover-btn">View Source Code</button>
      <button class="btn-getstarted hover-btn">Get Started</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-decentralized">
    <img class="decentralized" src="/images/Untitled_design__2_-removebg.png" alt="">

  </div>

  <div class="why-container">
    <div class="header-why">Why Choose PrivDono?</div>
  </div>



  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"/>
                      </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
          Transparent And Open-Source
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
          We pride ourselves on being honest and open about our software.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-lock-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M8 1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v4H6V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zm3 6V3a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"/>
                      </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
          Annoymous And Affordable
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
          Don't want to use card? We accept 10+ crypto currencies and even accept cash mail-ings, our service starts at $5 a month.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chat-left-dots-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4.414a1 1 0 0 0-.707.293L.854 15.146A.5.5 0 0 1 0 14.793V2zm5 4a1 1 0 1 0-2 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0zm4 0a1 1 0 1 0-2 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0zm3 1a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/>
                      </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
          Reliable Customer Service
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
          Our team will help walk you through how set up your annoymous donations so you don't have to do it alone.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-svg">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                      </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
          Easy To Use
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
          No code, or experience is required to set up your donations.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-text">Copyright DevExodus</div>
    <div class="footer-svg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"/>
          </svg> </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please check Html code. i think you forgot to add full html code

Comment: only head tag is there in your code. body is missing

Comment: @Neha just fixed it, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.left-elements` is a child of the nav bar you can, on small screen sizes, place it where you like using `position: absolute`. I've added a class to show you this and some javascript to make it clickable. I've removed the anchor tag from the navbar burger menu. I've annotated all the changes I've made so you can hopefully follow what I've done. Any questions just pop a comment in and I'll explain.

```js
// Added this script
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('.navbar-toggle').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    document.querySelector('.left-elements').classList.toggle('left-elements-display');
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.left-elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-inline-start: 1.5em;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-elements {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-inline-end: 4em;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.logo {
  padding-inline-start: 0.5em;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.btn-login {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #90E0EF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
  width: 8em;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 35rem;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-header {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  height: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-text {
  width: 40%;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .left-elements {
    display: none;
    /*added this */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5rem;
    top: 70%;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: fit-content;
    padding-block: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    /* end of added this */
  }
  /* added this */
  .left-elements-display {
    display: flex;
  }
  /* end of added this */
  .right-elements {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    /* added this */
    cursor: pointer;
    /*end of added this */
    display: flex;
    padding-inline-end: 2em;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.btn-container>button {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #90E0EF;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
  width: 11em;
}

.btn-sourcecode {
  background-color: #90E0EF;
}

.btn-getstarted {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-text {
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1112px) {
  .main-header {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 595px) {
  .main-header {
    font-size: 2rem;
    height: 20%;
  }
  .heading-text {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .decentralized {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  .main-header {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .btn-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .main-header {
    height: 30%;
  }
}

.container-decentralized {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 21rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.decentralized {
  height: 21em;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1112px) {
  .main-header {
    font-size: 3em;
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .decentralized {
    height: 15rem;
  }
}

.hover-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 0 rgba(0, 214, 243, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow ease-in 0.1s;
}

.why-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 12rem;
}

.header-why {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.card {
  background-color: #90E0EF;
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: #90E0EF solid 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  height: 17rem;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.card-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-text {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Screen larger than 600px 2 column */

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}


/* Screen larger than 900px 3 columns */

@media (min-width: 941px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href=""><img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/248x48?text=image" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left-elements">
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Pricing</a>
    <a href="">Integrations</a>
    <a href="">Support</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-elements">
    <a href="" class="btn-login hover-btn">Log In</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-toggle">
    <!--<a href="">  REMOVED THIS-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path fill="#90E0EF" fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
        </svg>
    <!--</a> REMOVED THIS-->
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="heading">
  <h1 class="main-header">A Powerful Decentralized, Open-Source Fundraising Software</h1>
  <p class="heading-text">Manage your donations without having your data stolen and sold without your consent.</p>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn-sourcecode hover-btn">View Source Code</button>
    <button class="btn-getstarted hover-btn">Get Started</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-decentralized">
  <img class="decentralized" src="/images/Untitled_design__2_-removebg.png" alt="">

</div>

<div class="why-container">
  <div class="header-why">Why Choose PrivDono?</div>
</div>



<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-svg">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path
              d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">
        Transparent And Open-Source
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        We pride ourselves on being honest and open about our software.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-svg">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-lock-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path
              d="M8 1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v4H6V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2zm3 6V3a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">
        Annoymous And Affordable
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        Don't want to use card? We accept 10+ crypto currencies and even accept cash mail-ings, our service starts at $5 a month.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-svg">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chat-left-dots-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path
              d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4.414a1 1 0 0 0-.707.293L.854 15.146A.5.5 0 0 1 0 14.793V2zm5 4a1 1 0 1 0-2 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0zm4 0a1 1 0 1 0-2 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0zm3 1a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">
        Reliable Customer Service
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        Our team will help walk you through how set up your annoymous donations so you don't have to do it alone.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-svg">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path
              d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="card-title">
        Easy To Use
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        No code, or experience is required to set up your donations.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer-text">Copyright DevExodus</div>
  <div class="footer-svg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z" />
      </svg> </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I understand completely what this does and what changes you made to achieve this. Appreciate it alot.